# Union on two selects with a different number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add one more column of output to my result set in MySQL. I can easily get these results by doing two separate queries, but I would like them to be in the same result set so I can export them together.

Anyway here is what I am doing:

```
select buildid, cast(status as char), eventtime from buildstatuses 
where statustype = 8)
union all (select schedulerid, "", "" from builds 
where builds.buildid in (select buildid from buildstatuses where statustype = 8));
```

I am only getting the columns listed in the initial select as output:

build    status    eventtime

I don't get the other column I want: schedulerid

any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: update

```
select buildstatuses.buildid, cast(status as char), eventtime, "" as schedulerid
from buildstatuses
inner join builds
on buildstatuses.buildid = builds.buildid
where buildstatuses.statustype = 8;
```

This is where I am at right now, the column id like to add is still showing up blank, even with the alias

Comment: you should first start with reading about this concept called joining tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select buildid, cast(status as char), eventtime, schedulerid from buildstatuses 
inner join builds on buildstatuses.buildid = builds.buildid
where statustype = 8
```

`UNION` will only select the columns that are common between both tables.

What you are looking for is a join.

Edit: Originally I misunderstood the question and suggested a change to the `union`.  I updated the answer to use a `join` which should give what you are looking for.

Comment: this just outputs a blank column where i would like scheduler id to be

Comment: @Hunter - What do you expect from UNION? It appends rows. If you want results from two tables to show up in the same row, you need to use JOIN instaed of UNION. Having said that, Alan's suggestion is the right way to go to create a result set that contains _independent_ rows from two tables. I'd just add that with his approach, one can also `select ..., NULL AS schedulerid FROM ...` if that makes more sense.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I think you are really looking for a join not a union and I updated the answer to do what I think you wanted.

Comment: Right, I agree that Alan's suggestion is the right way to go, but I wasn't clear above, schedulerid is in the builds table, so I cant select that from buildstatuses